# Queue with a singly linkedlist

Tags: linked-list, queue, singly-linked-list

A reference I'm using says the following:

> > For efficiency reasons, we choose the front of the queue to be at the head of the list, and the rear of the queue to be at the tail of the list. In this way, we remove from the head and insert at the tail.

I'm wondering why would it be bad to insert at the head and remove at the tail? Is it because in a singly linked list, removing a tail node is not so easy because you have to access the one before and the only way of doing that in a singly linked list is to start from the beginning?

Comment: yes.
Removing from the tail will reduce the performance. Since need to travel from starting.

At the User point of view adding in tail and removing from head or adding in head and removing from tail, both will give similar functionality. Because user point of view head and tail are the 2 end of the queue.

So adding in head and removing from tail doesn't have any useful.

Comment: Thank you mate, if you'll post this as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

yes. 
Removing from the tail will reduce the performance. Since need to travel from starting. At the User point of view adding in tail and removing from head or adding in head and removing from tail, both will give similar functionality. Because user point of view head and tail are the 2 end of the queue. So adding in head and removing from tail doesn't have any useful.